# Assigning array variables to int variables

Tags: array, variables

I need to control thousands of rgb leds.To make animations I want to assign led numbers(addressable led strip) to arrays.For example `floor[2]room[14]=106` 106 is the number of led,there are many floors and rooms.I want to change floor or room numbers with that way I will make animations.
  We can say its 92x30 pixel monitor.I tried to create list of floor and rooms but I couldnt make it.
  I'm new to programming,help please!

**Solved with this way `#define LEDNO(FLOOR, ROOM) ((ROOM) + (FLOOR * 92))`**

Comment: Are the LEDs in floor/room sequence? I.e., is floor[2]room[15] going to be LED 107?

Comment: yes,exactly.every floor has 92 rgb,and there is 30 floors.

Comment: Your Arduino has more than 8 K or RAM, right?

Comment: yes I'm using arduino due.

Comment: I'm already controlling all of leds,but I couldnt calibrate them.

Comment: sounds like you need to check out these guys (and similar projects) https://makezine.com/2012/11/18/worlds-biggest-led-cube/

Comment: are the LEDs ordered? LED number 1 in first room on first floor, no 2 in second room on first floor etc and the last number in the last room on the last floor? or is the mapping more complicated?

Comment: LEDs are ordered exactly as you said Juraj.

Comment: and on every floor is a same count of rooms?

Comment: yes,92 pixel on every floors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need to maintain a list.

Just calculate the LED index from the location:

```
int room = 14;
int floor = 2;

const int rooms = 92;

int led = room + (floor * rooms);
```

That is, each floor below the current one (floors and rooms count from 0) is a full row of rooms (92 * floors), and there are "room" extra rooms on this floor to add to it.

You could make a macro:

```
#define LEDNO(FLOOR, ROOM) ((ROOM) + (FLOOR * 92))
```

Then your LED number is just:

```
int led = LEDNO(2, 14);
```

Here's an example taken from your code:

```
void floorsup(){

  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness);

  for(int a=1;a<255;a+=40){
    for (int floor = 0; floor < 30; floor++) {
      for (int room = 0; room < 92; room++) {
        leds[LEDNO(floor, room)].setHSV(a, 255, 255);
      }
      FastLED.show();
      delay(300);
    }
    for (int floor = 0; floor < 30; floor++) {
      for (int room = 0; room < 92; room++) {
        leds2[LEDNO(floor, room)].setHSV(a, 255, 255);
      }
      FastLED.show();
      delay(300);
    }
    for (int floor = 0; floor < 30; floor++) {
      for (int room = 0; room < 92; room++) {
        leds3[LEDNO(floor, room)].setHSV(a, 255, 255);
      }
      FastLED.show();
      delay(300);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but with this way I cant light up many leds at the same time

Comment: What does this have to do with how many LEDs you can light up at once? This just gives you an LED number. What you do with that is up to you. I would use it to set an LED colour in the NeoPixel library. I don't think you quite understand exactly what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: yes but if I wanted to light whole fourth floor its gonna be easy with assigning them number.

Comment: They already have a number. What do you want to "assign"?

Comment: okay its long but I'm gonna share my code,you will understand what I mean

Comment: You have absolutely no need for your array for that code. Most of it can be replaced with a couple of loops and the macro I show above.

Comment: I have used a chunk of your code (the longest most wasteful portion) to demonstrate how you'd use it. The code is now readable.

Comment: ahhh now I got it! yes its really such a shame I know,I make like that with hurry.Let me obligate  more your code.At the first time I thought I'm gonna identify with int all numbers.

Comment: ohh man you just save me from a lot of works :D now I dont have to calibrate leds with python,I saw from another programmer in my company at the other project with the array way,so I thought I should make like that way.But with your way its saving me from a lot of works..

Comment: I'm talking too much sorry but I have one more question.How can I convert any image to RGB color code arrays?For example from uploaded image I will get RGB color codes for 92x30 pixels.Is it possible with python?

Comment: I have no idea about python. If I were scripting it I would do it in PHP since it has image functions right there for you - however I never need to these days, since the latest beta version of UECIDE has it all built in.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
#define MAX_FLOORS  92
#define MAX_ROOMS   30

struct floor_str {
  int Room[MAX_ROOMS];
} Floor[MAX_FLOORS];
```

You would then access an individual LED address like:

Floor[2].Room[14] = 106;

Comment: yes,I can take all led numbers from python on this format,but I wasnt know how to assign them.Thank you!

Comment: btw does it should be like `struct floor_str {
  int room[MAX_ROOMS];
 floor[MAX_FLOORS]; } `?

Comment: No. You make a struct of rooms as an array and make an array of them as floors.

Comment: I already figure out with another way but I would like to learn your method also.Could you check your code again? its giving error.

Comment: The syntax was correct but 'floor' appears to be already defined as something else.  An easy solution is to use 'Floor' instead.  (edited the solution above)